# how to make two variables share a math.random value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Suceeded in randomizing a quote but now the values name and quote don't match, is there a way to make `json.name` and `json.quote` share the same random value? so Einstein's quote isn't matched with the name Nightingale.

```
let url =;

$.getJSON( url, function( json ) {

let rand = function getRandom() {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1  ;
}

//console.log(rand());

document.write(" &#34;" + json[rand()].quote +"&#34;" + "  by " 
+json[rand()].name );


});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.write(" &#34;" + json[rand()].quote +"&#34;" + "  by " 
+json[rand()].name );
```

everytime you use `rand()`, it will generate a different number, so `json[rand()].quote` and `json[rand()].name` will be different because you are using different keys, so save `rand()` in a variable first and then use it, like:

```
var randNumber = rand();
document.write(" &#34;" + json[randNumber].quote +"&#34;" + "  by " +json[randNumber].name );
```